# Am I using window.location.replace right? (also am I writing commands right?)

Tags: javascript, command, window

I kind of get all my coding information from the internet rather than a class, and certain answers I can't really understand so hopefully I'll get a simple answer to a possibly stupid question.

In a part of my website, I've got a button which brings up a window.prompt and it asks the viewer if they would like to go to one page (I've called it Timeline because it's a timeline of my art portfolio) or to the other. The prompt works perfectly fine, and I attempted to code it so that if, for example, the user typed in "Timeline" the webpage would automatically redirect them to the Timeline page (which for me is empty at the moment) and vice versa if they typed in "Term 1" (the name of the other page.) I found out about window.location.replace and assumed that it would work if I tried to get it to redirect the user, but when I run my webpage nothing happens after I type in the prompt window. I checked the Developer Tools on Chrome and it didn't report any errors, so is it just me typing some stuff wrong?

```
   function promptFunction() {
    var choice = window.prompt ("Would you like to go to the Timeline or to Term 1?")

    if (choice === "Timeline")
        function redirTime() {
        window.location.replace() ("Timeline.html");
        }

    else if (choice ==="timeline") 
        function redirTime() {
        window.location.replace() ("Timeline.html");
        }

    else if (choice ==="Term 1") 
        function redirFirstTerm() {
        window.location.replace() ("Term 1.html")
        }

    else if (choice ==="term 1") 
        function redirFirstTerm() {
        window.location.replace() ("Term 1.html")
        }   

    };
```

This again is probably me looking for an answer that's right under my nose, so if the answer is something obvious, sorry ^^'

**Edit:** I've got an answer now; thank you very much! (I did think it was something to do with the way I was typing it, sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted creates, based on `choice` a function, but the function is never executed (or you omitted this code).

Additionally the `window.location.replace()("...")` part is wrong. It calls the `replace` function on `window.location` with no arguments and uses the result of this function call again as function an passes e.g. "Timeline.html" as argument.

If all you want to do is setting the location, assign it directly, e.g. `window.location = "https://stackoverflow.com"` or in your case `window.location.href = "Timeline.html"` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).